# Do randomly generated 2D points clump together, and how do I stop it?

Tags: random, geometry, 2d

Say you have a 2D area and you want to generate random points within it, by setting

```
x = random() * width 
y = random() * height
```

do the points clump around the centre of the area? I remember reading something saying they would, but I can't quite figure out why, and how to prevent it.

Comment: There is a mathematical proof that random events will occur in groups. I read it years ago and don't recall the details, but I believe I saw it in a book "Great Ideas in Operations Research". (I remember titles better than proofs...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the distribution of the random number generator.  Assuming a perfectly even distribution, then the points are likely to be distributed in a reasonably uniform way.

Also, asking if they clump around the middle is pre-supposing that you don't have the ability to test this!

Comment: ha ha yes I just tested it with 100,000 points. they do form clumps, but not in the middle.

Comment: It wouldn't be random if they _didn't_ form clumps somewhere. As the points are random, the distances between them must vary as well. Hence, there must be some small distances = clump of points together. (This margin is of course too narrow for the truly marvelous proof )

Answer (score 6):

Yes. The fewer points you have, the more they will appear to form clusters.

To avoid this, you can use "stratified sampling". it basically means you divide your surface evenly in smaller areas and place your points in there.

For your example, you would divide the square in n*n subsquares. Each point would be placed randomly inside it's subsquare. You can even adjust the randomness factor to make the pattern more or less random/regular:

```
// I assume random() return a number in the range [0, 1).

float randomnessFactor = 0.5;
int n = 100;

for(int ySub=0; ySub<n; ++ySub){
    for(int xSub=0; xSub<n; ++xSub){

        float regularity = 0.5 * (1-randomnessFactor);

        x = regularity + randomnessFactor * random() + xSub / (float) (n-1);
        y = regularity + randomnessFactor * random() + ySub / (float) (n-1);

        plot(x, y);

    }
}
```

The reason this works is that you don't actually want randomness. (Clumps are random.) You want the points evenly spread, but without the regular pattern. Placing the points on a grid and offsetting them a bit hides the regularity.

Comment: This is a surprisingly good idea. As of today, the code has some typos/copy-paste errors, but I was able to use this idea to get some nice results, and I'm grateful for that. Thank you ~10-year-ago @geon.

Comment: Note that this code produces results in the range 0.5 - 1.5. Subtract 0.5 from the resulting x and y values to get 0 - 1 as indicated in the post. Thanks @geon, this was perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Truly random points will create clusters (or clumps) - it's the effect that can cause confusion when plotting real world data (like cancer cases) and lead to people thinking that there are "hot spots" which must be caused by something.

However, you also need to be careful when generating random numbers that you don't create a new generator every time you want a new number - this will use the same seed value which will result in all the values clustering about a point.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, randomly generated points do not clump in the center of the area since every pixel of your screen has the same probability of being selected.

While numbers generated with random() are not *truely* random, they  will be sufficent for putting objects randomly on your screen.

Answer (score 1):

If the random number generator's random() function yields a gaussian distribution, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

You get a clump at the origin if you use polar coordinates instead of carthesian:

```
r = rand() * Radius;
phi = rand() * 2 * Pi;
```

The reason is that statistically, the circle `r=[0,1]` will contain as many points as the ring `r=[1,2]` even though the ring is three times larger.

Comment: +1 for thinking out of the box and pointing me to an interesting - and unexpected- phenomenon

Answer (score 1):

Pseudorandom points won't necessarily clump "around the center" of an area, but they *will* tend to cluster in various random points in an area; in fact these clumps often occur more frequently than people think. A more even distribution of space is often achieved by using so-called *quasirandom* or [*low-discrepancy sequences*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence), such as the [Sobol sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobol_sequence), whose Wikipedia article shows a graphic illustrating the difference between Sobol and pseudorandom sequences.

Answer (score -1):

They will not clump, but will form various interesting patterns, in 2d or 3d, depending on the generator you use.